# C# Oledb Connection can't update

Tags: c#, database

I'm an IT student who's always wanted to be in code hell (nah not really I really like this path I'm taking) so I'm just a beginner at using database.

so I have this problem of mine, specifically, when I try to update the form or at least the label itself, I can't connect to the Access Database I'm trying to get data from when I press the button, I like to know if I can even update the form or it's following items ***without losing connection to the database***

if it's possible, and a better solution if you may as well, thanks in advance!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = (1 * 1000);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string select = "select Input from tbl_Dta1";
        string connectionValue = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=TestDatabase.accdb";
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection nConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionValue))
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(select, nConnection);
                nConnection.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string update = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    label1.Text = update;
                }

                dr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Data source");
        }
    }
```

btw, the code I just made is actually a test code
I'm testing if the timer would interrupt the connection
and the purpose of the current content of this code is just to test if the database cell I'm getting is right or wrong

Comment: So you wanna update the Label based on changes to the database ?

Comment: yes, it's exactly what I want to do

Comment: or what I actually intend to do in the future btw. (sorry I didn't get to edit the previous comment)

Comment: Essentially you should not mind losing connection, just use the same connection string to open connection and get the data you wish. And update it directly from the tick function.

Comment: likewise creating a function/method that contains the block of code I have and then using that method inside the tick function right?

Comment: Yeah something like that. You could do a try method, that returns true or false if it succeds, and have and out parameter that is updated if true.

Comment: thanks! I just realized how dumb I am not to think of what you answered me
holy damn I'm so sorry for even wasting a bit of your time!